# Error setting value of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I initialize this `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
define TAREFA      @"TAREFA"  
define DATA_ITEM        @"DATA"   
define HORA_ITEM        @"HORAS"  
define ID          @"ID"  
define STATE       @"NA"  
define APROVED     @"APROVED"  
define REJECTED    @"REJECTED" 

    itensArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i< [listagens size]; i++)
    {   
        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [[listagens item:i] WI_ID], ID,
                                        [[listagens item:i] WI_TEXT], TAREFA,
                                        [[listagens item:i] WI_CD], DATA_ITEM,                                            
                                        [[listagens item:i] WI_CT], HORA_ITEM,                                                                                     
                                        STATE, STATE,
                                        nil];

        [itensArray addObject:tmpDictionary];           
    }
```

Later on, i do the following:

```
    for (int i=0; i<[itensArray count]; i++) 
    {
        if ([[[itensArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:ID] isEqualToString:cell.idLabel.text]) {
            [[itensArray objectAtIndex:i] setString:APROVED forKey:STATE];
            break;
        }
    }
```

I initialize the array, then later on, i change a string of the NSMutableDictionary. When i set the value i get the following runtime error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setString:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b7d170'

It appears i´m not changing the value correctly. Is it a syntax error? How is it done?

Comment: Ghetto style! Already corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you misspelled the name of the method.

```
// WRONG
[[itensArray objectAtIndex:i] setString:APROVED forKey:STATE];

// GOOD
[[itensArray objectAtIndex:i] setValue:APROVED forKey:STATE];
```

Comment: And it's probably even better form to be using `setObject:forKey:` instead of the value one, assuming you're not using KVC here. (Though it will do the same thing.)

Comment: @quixoto, as far as I know, the `-setObject:forKey:` method always makes a hard copy of the key, even if the key is just a string only as it is in case of the `KVC` normally. therefore, the `-setValue:forKey:` is a bit faster however the key always must be a string but this should be enough in the 99% of cases, basically I would not recommend to use it - but if you have to use complex classes as keys, of course you must use the `-setObject:forKey:` method and you have to pay the price of it as well.

Comment: @holex: I don't believe this is true. Documentation for `NSMutableDictionary` says that this method just uses `setObject:forKey:`, with special remove behavior for a nil value. Additionally, since this is a KVC protocol method, and you're not using it for KVC here (probably), I would always prefer the `setObject:forKey:` primitive.

Comment: @quixoto, according to the **[NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**, it is in the documentation black and white at the `-setObject:forKey:` method description, I quote: _The key is copied (using `copyWithZone:`; keys must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol)_. maybe you are right but the official documentation says something else. if your keys are strings only, you wouldn't need to use this method, it is just wasting the resources for nothing.

Comment: @holex: Yup, the key is always copied in a dictionary-- no argument there. However, you're getting that same behavior in both cases. Look on that same page at `-setValue:forKey:`, and you'll find this: *This method adds value and key to the dictionary using setObject:forKey:, unless value is nil in which case the method instead attempts to remove key using removeObjectForKey:.* By using `-setValue:forKey:`, you're getting the same result, with an extra level of indirection, both semantically and in actual performance.

Answer (score 1):

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setString:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b7d170'

NSMutableDictionary has no setString:forKey: method.

Try setObject:forKey:

```
[[itensArray objectAtIndex:i] setObject:APROVED forKey:STATE];
```

Comment: I have the method. Available: iOS (5.0 and later)